# Why dont more HR personnel adequately screen IT applicants?

Tags: automated-testing

I get so many resumes from people stating they know Selenium, while in practice, they cannot do more than a macro - most not even that.

These test candidates typically seem to be housewives looking for a first job.  It's frustrating and a waste of time and money.

Comment: Please reveal your location... for any suitable local candidates who are here

Comment: @MichaelDurrant That would unnecessarily localize the question. If Rollo is looking to use SE to get candidates, his best bet would be to use [Stack Overflow Talent](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent)

Comment: not disagreeing.  just noting that I know several candidates.  if I knew location I would consider referring them. trying to help Rob

Comment: For some positions, I think that's pretty much what I'm looking for. For jobs requiring more experience, I use some amount of years of experience as a requirement and tell my HR person what to look for on the resume. Then I usually phone screen and ask them to describe what they did with selenium in their listed experience and how they organized code. Most of my in person interviews are pretty productive after that.

Answer (score 2):

HR personnel are not skilled at testing the skills you need.  You need to partner with them and jointly develop skills and techniques and processes to screen candidates.  This takes time and dedication - think days and weeks, not minutes and hours.

The demand for these skills is huge.  However as will all tech jobs today, just posting a link or a profile on linkedIn will just lead to thousands of resumes, 99% of which will not be a fit.

I recommend you make sure you are spending your time:

- Going to (or hosting) any local quality engineering meetups
- Going to QA/QE conferences
- Reviewing candidate profiles on *this* site where those who know, share and teach stand out
- Working with a technical recruiter to screen candidates on what you want

Accept that all ways will cost a lot in time, effort and dollars.
You'll get results based on the efforts you take.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot more to working in QA than having QA experience.  When I came to my current position, I had zero QA experience and never even heard of Selenium.

Now, three years later, I am the local Senior Automation Test Lead.  I teach the new hires.  Why did they hire someone to fill a position that had zero experience in it?  Granted I'm an exception.  I was a software developer for over 30 years, and yet I never coded in Java.  I learned that while here, too.

They saw the potential in me.  Saw that I worked for one of my previous employers for over 25 years, ran my own company for five, was sharp and a quick learner.

Those things don't show on a resume, nor does confidence.

My only point is experience matters, but not necessarily in the job at hand.